# Control item count per column with flex/grid

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have something like this

```css
.items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #cecece;

  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 8px);
  margin: 4px;
  background: #16B6B6FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item" style="order: 1">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="order: 3">2</div>
  <div class="item" style="order: 5">3</div>
  <div class="item" style="order: 2">4</div>
  <div class="item" style="order: 4">5</div>
  <div class="item" style="order: 6">6</div>
  <div class="item" style="order: 99">7</div>
  <div class="item" style="order: 98">8</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to move `8` to below `7` and still keep 2 column layouts without any changes to the HTML structure?

Expected outcome:

```
1     4
2     5
3     6
      7
      8
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. TL;DR - I changed to use [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
.items {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background: #cecece;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.item {
  background: #16B6B6FF;
}

.item:nth-child(n + 4) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```